# How to serialize a non List<T> collection in protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Observe the following code:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class C
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var m = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
    m.AutoCompile = true;
    m.Add(typeof(IList<string>), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(ObservableCollection<int>));

    var c = new C { Tags = new ObservableCollection<string> { "hello" } };
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      Serializer.Serialize(ms, c);
      ms.Position = 0;
      var c2 = Serializer.Deserialize<C>(ms);
      Debug.Assert(c.Tags.Count == c2.Tags.Count);
      Debug.Assert(c.Tags.GetType() == c2.Tags.GetType());
    }
  }
}
```

The last assertion fails, because c2.Tags is a regular `List<T>`, rather than `ObservableCollection<T>`. In effect, the AddSubType statement is ignored.

Is it possible to fix it without using surrogates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists etc are mapped to the "repeated" syntax from the .proto spec. This embeds directly from the parent object directly. There is no facility to store any additional metadata.

The code has been tweaked to highlight this rather than silently ignore it.

You can specify the default concrete type to use, but only that.

Comment: I am not trying to fool the framework. I am just learning its abilities. I have already mentioned that I am trying to port an existing application and it is not wire friendly at all. It only means more work in the surrogate department. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: @Mark I really appreciate the edge cases, actually. You are testing me, but only to positive effect.